# HTTP server only serves "/" from browser

Tags: go

I basically cut and pasted the example to make a web server from this link:  http://thenewstack.io/building-a-web-server-in-go/

Posted the code here:
http://play.golang.org/p/RvEr7E-v9q

I run the server and put in browser "localhost:8080" and this calls the `hello(w,r)` handler as expected. When trying from browser "localhost/stuff:8080" it doesn't even call the `ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)`

What fundamentally ridiculous thing am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried localhost:8080/stuff ? The port number should be before the path, not after it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You're not using a valid url. The port number comes before the path. The scheme below describes a url. You hsould have `localhost:8080/whatever/the/path/is` and never `localhost/some/path/this/should/never/work/because/its/not/valid:8080`

scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[?query][#fragment]